# Pull a value from a text file to use as a comparitor

Tags: python, text-processing

I need the pull the temperature from a text file, and then use the value as a comparitor to run one or the other python script.  the data looks like this:

```
time=14:10
temp=22.4  <-----  I need this value
tempTL=18.7
tempTH=29.9
intemp=66.4
```

I have seen some examples on how to pull the temperature from this, 22.4 in my example.
I am not sure how to make it a value to compare with.
I need if temp < 30 then run myfile1.py  else myfile2.py

```
sed -n 's/^temp=\(.*\)/\1/p' < realtimegauges.txt
echo temp=`sed -n 's/^temp=\(.*\)/\1/p' < txt`
```

Not sure how to pass the temp as a varable to compare with.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Which exact task are you having difficulty to code ? Reading the temp line and extracting the value ? Comparing with another value ? ..

Comment: I am not sure how to make it a value to compare with. I need if temp < 30 then run myfile1.py else myfile2.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the input file lines until the needed `temp=` is found, extract the temperature value, break the file processing and check the needed condition to run a certain file with [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
import subprocess

with open('realtimegauges.txt') as f:
    t_val = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('temp='):
            t_val = float(line.split('=')[1])
            break
    if t_val < 30:
        subprocess.run(['python', 'myfile1.py'])
    else:
        subprocess.run(['python', 'myfile2.py'])
```

Comment: If I am following you,  your passing the value of "temp=" to t_val    I understand the rest of the program.   Could the value be tmp_val  or h_val   with the "_val" designating it as a value?

Comment: @BobW, you can give a variable name whatever you like, desirably making it descriptive (basing on its contents)